Spring Pulsar Admin cannot create topic
I tried to use Spring Pulsar to create a topic on an Apache Pulsar instance in the cloud, but after implementing the connection settings, I keep getting the following error: Caused by: org.apache.pulsar.shade.org.asynchttpclient.exception.RemotelyClosedException: Remotely closed. Is there something wrong with my configuration?
spring:
  pulsar:
    admin:
      service-url: http://localhost:8080/
      authentication:
        plugin-class-name: org.apache.pulsar.client.impl.auth.AuthenticationTls
        param:
          tlsCertFile: /Users/user/Desktop/project/my-project/tls-ca-cert.pem
          tlsKeyFile: /Users/user/Desktop/project/my-project/tls-key.pem
          trustedCertFile: /Users/user/Desktop/project/my-project/tls-ca-cert.pem

spring boot version: 3.3.2

The Pulsar admin url uses the (http|https) scheme rather than the (pulsar|pulsar+ssl) scheme.

References:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-pulsar/reference/reference/pulsar-admin.html#pulsar-admin-client
https://pulsar.apache.org/api/admin/3.3.x/org/apache/pulsar/client/admin/PulsarAdminBuilder.html#serviceHttpUrl(java.lang.String))


Hi @onobc,  I tried switching to HTTP, but got this error: Caused by: org.apache.pulsar.shade.org.asynchttpclient.exception.RemotelyClosedException: Remotely closed. What are your thoughts?

Hi @j-hu, this is likely something related to the TLS connection/configuration. This AsyncHttpClient issue describes some possible causes. Please take a look at the TLS section of the Spring for Apache Pulsar ref docs as it points to some possibly helpful example configurations.
